# ruby extend system class ActiveRecord::Relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I would like to add a method to ActiveRecord::Relation which returns a singular result, and raises an exception when there are 0 or >1 results.
Found something at [SO about overriding find](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/314786/whats-the-cleanest-way-to-override-activerecords-find-for-both-models-and-coll) which I adapted, but is not working, resulting in method not found

```
module FindOne
  def self.included(base)

    def find_exactly_one
      if self.size > 1
        raise "Expected exactly one, got #{self.size}"
      end
      first!
    end
  end
end

ActiveRecord::Relation.send :include, FindOne
```

Any ideas?

ruby 2.1.5 rails 4.0

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra `end` statement in your module which will cause a syntax error.  If you delete it your method should be included.

Comment: Sorry, copy paster error. Tried, and still same result. Does the location of the file matter? Tried /app/models/fond_one.rb and /app/models/concerns/find_one.rb

Comment: Trying putting it in a file in `config/initializers`.  Then restart the server.